# How can you check which options vim was compiled with?

Tags: vim

I'd like to know which compilation options were used for my Vim binary. Is there any way to query this?

Specifically, I'm interested in if it has Python support enabled.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can see everything vim was compiled with by executing

```
:version
```

To query for an exact feature like python you can use the `has()` function with the feature you are looking for. The code below will return a 1 if it has the feature or 0 if it does not.

```
:echo has('python')
```

For a list of features see `:h +feature-list`

For more information see:

```
:h :version
:h has(
:h feature-list
```

Comment: For sake of completeness: For vimscript a syntax example is `if has('clipboard')`,  `set mouse=a`,  `end`. Can't be bothered to read help if I already read SO ;-)

Comment: When I run `:version` it shows `+python/dyn and +python3/dyn`. But echo has('python') returns 0. So, why is there a difference and which one should I go with?

Comment: `:version` shows what Vim is compiled with. In your case `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn` which are dynamically loaded versions of python. According to `:h python-dynamic` this means Vim will search for the needed python dll libraries and if found you can use python. Trying `has('python')` will attempt to load python dynamically and return the results (See `:h has-python`). Therefore `has('python')` is the preferred method.

Answer (score 21):

Use `vim --version`.  Mine shows:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 20 2012 13:16:02)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
-toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
  system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
    user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
     user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
 fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `vi --version`, which shows compilation options and the compiler command.